# Custom rendering when using server side processing

Tags: javascript, datatables

I was wondering if the rendering of the table after receiving an ajax response can be modified. This seems related to the `render` function described here: https://www.datatables.net/manual/orthogonal-data.

My server returns Data like

```
{
    "name":       
                       {
                        id: "123456",
                        value: "Tiger Nixon"
                        }
}
```

I want to add to each name cell the id of the name as `data-attribute` or as id for the `td` and want to add a `.on( "click", handler )` for each cell.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the [columns.createdCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) function.

The answer of Gyrocode is correct for an old DataTables version.

Comment: According to the manual you're mentioning above `createdCell` can be used as a complement to `columns.render`. The code shown in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29904996/3549014) is for the latest DataTables version (1.10.x).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DT_RowData` or `DT_RowAttr` (requires DataTables 1.10.5 or higher) parameters in your returned data to assign attributes to `<tr>` element which you can later retrieve in click handler, see [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) chapter in the manual.

Alternatively you can use `render` method but it may not be as effective. I assumed below that index of your `name` column is `0` and that you want to set `data-id` attribute.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "columnDefs": [{
      "data": "name.value",
      "targets": 0,
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         if(type === 'display'){
            $('#example').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$().attr('data-id', full['name']['id']);
         }

         return data;
      }
   }]
});
```

You can add click event handler using the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       // Define DataTables initialization options here 
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function(){

       // Use table to access various API function
       //
       // For example:
       // var data_cell = table.cell(this).data();

    });
});
```